# How can I host a create a simple login portal that can be accessed by different users over a same local network?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm planning to make an Instagram for web for my school project, but i don't know how to give access to a page from the server to multiple users. Make note that all these things are happening offline and the webpage will be accessed to all those users who are connected to my local hotspot (or the computer hotspot on which I'm going to host the server).I don't know a thing about how to connect two users. please help.
Thanks

Comment: So you should be researching how to setup a server/localhost to allow inbound connection only (local area network access)... What sort of server will you be running? Have you even looked at your options with that?

Comment: where is the problem in two people connecting to a local wifi hotspot?

Comment: the problem is @jeff that when two people are connected on the same wifi hotspot and when they enter the same localHost address in their web browser then how I'm i supposed to show the same login page?

Answer (score 1):

this steps are for XAMPP over the same local network:

1. Get your internal IP or static ip  (ipv4, example: 192.168.1.106).
2. Open XAMPP>apache>conf>httpd.conf file
3. Find the line  #Listen 12.34.56.78:80 or #Listen 0.0.0.0:80
4. Change the IP address in that line and replace it with the static IP (192.168.1.106)
5. Save the httpd.conf file ensuring that the server is pointed to #Listen
   192.168.1.106:80
6. to connect from another pc just write http://192.168.1.106/myapp

hope it helps.